# Is there any horizontal skip after which the space character `\ ` is removed automatically?

Tags: spacing, plain-tex

Let's consider the following TeX macro:

`\def\theorem#1{Theorem (#1).\enspace}`

Try to use it:

`\theorem{Dirac} A simple graph with $n$ vertices\dots`

Then TeX produces two spaces after "Theorem (Dirac).", an `\enspace` and a regular space `\`, as expected. Of course, there are some workarounds, e.g.

`\theorem{Dirac}A simple graph with $n$ vertices\dots`,

which is ugly (even if I use `%` after `\theorem{Dirac}`), and I will forget this.

Is there any clean way to replace `\enspace` to some more clever horizontal skip in the macro?

EDIT (2nd question): 
What can I do in "reverse order", i.e. when my macro starts with \enspace (you can think of a \qed-like macro here), and I want to use that macro after a regular space?

Comment: If I understand well what you want, it suffices to use  the `nonumberplain` theoremstyle (from the `ntheorem` package)!

Comment: @Bernard This is tagged [tag:plain-tex]

Comment: @egreg: Oops! Sorry, I skimmed the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\enspace\ignorespaces
```

But are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: I think I want to do that, thanks. What are the drawbacks? (Except that I may forget that I have an \ignorespaces at the end of my macro.)

Comment: @GáborV.Nagy just seems a strange space to use:-) also if it is intended to be an inline heading I'm more used to the latex definitions which would not only ignore spaces but blank lines in that position as the heading is saved and inserted at the start of the paragraph to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: `\enspace` has no stretch, so if the line isn't full, but is broken to a new line, that space will be fixed, while the rest of the line may be spaced out and look rather unattractive.  this is subjective, but i've never liked the looks of lines spaced that way.